# Avoiding CORS restrictions on the Fetch API in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using the Fetch API in my React+Redux app like this:

```
fetch("http://news.at.zhihu.com/api/4/news/before/20160127").
```

The app is running in Chrome and I also set the `--disable-web-security` argument when I open Chrome. However, I still get the CORS issue:

> Fetch API cannot load http://news.at.zhihu.com/api/4/news/before/20160127. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

If I use XMLHTTPRequest, it works well. It looks like that the `--disable-web-security` can not work well with Fetch API.

Does anyone know how to use Fetch API without worrying about CORS issue?
I can not modify response header such as 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' since the services are not in my charge.

Comment: you could use a fetch polyfill...

Comment: @dandavis In fact ,I am using the fetch polyfill of 'isomorphic-fetch'. It has the issue mentioned above.

Comment: you'd have to mod it to get chrome to ignore the native fetch()... i can't see it on github ATM...

Comment: @dandavis Could you give me a detailed example of how to do it, please?

Comment: ex: on https://github.com/github/fetch/blob/master/fetch.js , replace each instance of "fetch" with "fitch", then use "fitch" in your code, or simply comment out line 5 of that file and let it clobber chrome's built-in fetch().